# Messenger webhook is not triggering messaging_referrals and messaging_postbacks events when a conversation is started via an ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-ads-api, messenger

I have created an ad that clicks to messenger using Facebook ads API.
But I am unable to figure out how to set referral_id or postback payload while creating the Ad. I am receiving only the messages but not Ad ID or Campaign ID.

Is it necessary to set any such payloads? because [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/ctm-ads) says

- **messaging_referrals** – This webhook will be triggered when a conversation is started via an ad, with the exception of an ad with a postback, Get Started button, or persistent menu*

Page is subscribed to both messaging_referrals and messaging_postbacks webhooks. Webhook URL is also working, the messages sent are received by webhook.

Please note that I haven't received approval for *pages_messaging* permission from Facebook. I am testing on test pages.